# Something dangerous that you can't go without?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun that means something dangerous, but it is still a necessary danger so you keep using it anyway.

**Examples:**

- A power-tool might be necessary for a mechanic, even though it could kill them.
- Someone who is on powerful drugs might regret having to take them, but still take them, as the risk of addiction is better than the immense pain.

Sentence: "I don't want to use it, but the ___ might be our only/best option."

Comment: Probably "the **risk** might be our only option" would work. That or "It's dangerous, but we'll just have to risk that."

Comment: While these are both two words, I think "necessary evil" or "lesser evil" fit.

Comment: Not a single word, but for the mechanic example, [_occupational hazard_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/occupational-hazard) comes close.

Comment: "I don't want to use it, but **it** might be our **least worst** option."

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use it, but the ***necessary evil*** might be our only/best option.

[(Cambridge definition)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/necessary-evil)

Comment: Works great for the drug example, e.g. chemotherapy, but I certainly wouldn't call a power tool a necessary evil. For as much as I love my tools, they simply cannot all be works of the devil!

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with a two word description. A "calculated risk" or even a "necessary risk" would be options.

Answer (score 1):

There might be nothing that matches this exact meaning. But the closest I can think of is a **double-edged sword**.

> From the notion that if two sides of the same blade are sharp, it cuts both ways.
>
> (idiomatic) A benefit that is also a liability, or (a benefit) that carries some significant but not-so-obvious cost or risk.

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double-edged_sword))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but -

## Indispensable

> : Absolutely necessary or requisite; that one cannot do without.

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indispensable#English))

Therefore -

> I don't want to use it, but the ***indispensability*** might be our
> only/best option.

Comment: Quick, hand me the indispensability!   I'm seeing a lot of forcing of the right word into the wrong part of the sentence on this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Jeopardy**, **perilious** can be affixed with the pith of the sentence.